# How to adjust the height and make the bacgroud of this toast code transparent.?

Tags: android

```
sas12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub"                                                                    "
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "                                                                    ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.flushed_skin);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.show();
        toastView.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
        toast.show();               
    }
});
```

How to adjust the height and make the bacgroud of this toast code transparent.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried to modify the default Toast before but you can create a custom layout for your Toast, and then set the android:alpha in the layout file.

**Static Call so that you can call it from anywhere:**

```
public static void showDialog(Context context, String text)
{   

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View toastLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom, null);

    // Notify the user
    TextView textView = (TextView) toastLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(text);             
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setDuration(1000);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.setView(toastLayout);
    toast.show();               

}
```

**Layout File toast_custom.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="20dp"     
android:alpha="0.5"
>    

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"        
     />
```

Comment: but this toast is holding an image @Maurice

Comment: you can adjust my example and put an ImageView in the layout instead of the TextView